# Trying to find the percent change of dollars between weeks within groups R

Tags: r, dplyr, lag, difference

I have a df (that is much larger) similar to as follows:

```
df = data.frame(r_id = c(1, 1 ,1, 1, 2,2,2,2, 3,3,3,3), s_id = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11,12),
                week = c(2021080801, 2021080101, 2021072501, 2021071801, 2021080801, 2021080101, 2021072501, 2021071801, 2021080801, 2021080101, 2021072501, 2021071801),
                price = c(96992.88, 104458.36, 106485.10, 105094.09, 103550.74, 
                          104990.28, 109912.51, 116662.20, 113178.26, 111779.15, 120553.04, 123132.30))
```

the column r_id is grouped into different categories. Each group contains a certain number of weeks and an associated dollar amount for each week. I am trying to find the percent change between each dollar amount for the week prior within each group and save it in its own column in the dataframe. For example for r_id 1, I want to calculate the percent difference from week 2021080801 to week 2021080101, then week 2021080101 to week 2021072501 and so on. However,  week 2021071801 would not have any percent change because there is no week preceeding it within the groups.

I know how to get the difference just using lag by doing:

```
df = df %>% group_by(r_id) %>%
  mutate(change = price - lag(price))*100/lag(price))
```

But the order is reversed, and the percentages when applied to my larger dataset seem to be off...

Comment: In your code you have brackets misplaced in `mutate`. Can you show your expected output?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps use `lead`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(r_id) %>%
    mutate(change = (price - lead(price)) * 100 /lead(price))
```